# Drag (and drop) file from wx.FileDialog window does not work in MacOS

Tags: python, macos, user-interface, wxpython

Here is my *user story*:

> After clicking on a particular button, a modal dialog box appears,
>   containing a single large icon representing a single file, and an OK
>   button. The header of the dialog box reads: "Please drag and drop this
>   file onto application APPX, then click OK". The dialog box disappears
>   after clicking OK.

Here is what I tried on MacOS 10.9.5, Python 2.7.8, wx 3.0.1.1:

```
import wx, os
class MyForm(wx.Frame):
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Demo")
        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        openFileDlgBtn = wx.Button(panel, label="Show FileDialog")
        openFileDlgBtn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onOpenFile)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(openFileDlgBtn, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5) 
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def onOpenFile(self, event):
        dlg = wx.FileDialog(
            self, message="Please drag and drop this file onto your favorite text editor, then click OK",
            defaultDir=os.getcwd(),
            defaultFile="*.txt",
            wildcard="TXT files (*.txt)|*.txt",
            style=wx.OPEN
            )
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            pass
        dlg.Destroy()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyForm()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Notes: I have no control on the external application; which will just open the file. The wxDialog does not completely fit my requirements, since it displays folder navigation elements as well as other (greyed out) files. But that's not the main issue.

The problem/question:

> The wxDialog will not let me **drag and drop** any file on MacOS. It works well on Windows and Linux (see comments). How to make it work on MacOS? What else than a FileDialog could I try? Ideally I'd have a simple frame showing the file to be dragged. Thanks.

Comment: The FileDialog allows DnD for me on Linux with wxPython 2.8.12. What OS and wx version are you using? It appears that the native file dialog on Windows also allows DnD. Not sure what you're seeing.

Comment: MacOS 10.9 but I intend that software to be cross-platform. I'll check wx version when I'm at home/work.

Comment: I just tried on Win7 64-bits, and DnD works! @Mike Driscoll tells me that it works on Linux, so it might be a Mac problem..

Comment: I slightly edited my code so that it is stand-alone and easier to copy/paste it.

Comment: You should cross-post to the wxPython Google group. They might have some ideas.

Comment: [post on wxPython Google group](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/wxpython-users/fYAVYd5odoI/KX7u4DfEyq0J)